# Is there any good redmine plugin for integration testing?

Tags: testing, plugins, redmine

Actually we would like to follow this procedure for testing
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/testing/integration-testing-whywhathow.html

And I'm trying to find a redmine plugin that would do this job but so far I could find only testing plugins that are related to automated tests which we already cover with Jenkins.

So what is needed is what the link above describes just as redmine plugin. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you want Redmine to do the job.  You could use it to plan the test cases and track the results.  You could do this with out-of-the-box functionality, by creating a handful of custom fields and some statuses.

Custom fields:  make one field for each of the columns in the article's Sample Test Case Table.

Statuses:  create a few statuses such as Draft & Approved (to be used during the planning phase), and Failed, Passed, Closed (to be used while testing is underway).

If you're going to have multiple iterations of integration testing, you can use the Versions functionality to plan them and to track progress on each wave of testing.

If I'm missing the point, or if there's some missing functionality that you'd need a plugin for, I am interested in learning more about what you mean.